# Error with firebase auth upon sign-up for react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Whenever I try to sign-up locally, I get this error:

```
"auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
```

Upon sign-up, I'm simply redirecting the user to a new page and that's all.

I read that it could be a problem with the service worker made with `create-react-app`, but I'm not entirely sure if it's a good idea to disable it.

This is how I'm handling sign-ups:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailValue, this.state.passValue)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })
    this.handleAuthChange()
}

handleAuthChange() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            window.location = 'thank-you'
            let email = user.email
            console.log(email + " logged in")
        } else {
            window.location = ""
            console.log("not logged in")
        }
    })
}
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `handleAuthChange()` function should probably be called in the success function once sign-in is done considering you want to start the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` listener after the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function call is made.

```
var self = this;
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailValue, 
this.state.passValue)
    .then(function(userData){
         self.handleAuthChange();
    })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
    })
}
```

A better idea I guess could be to start the listener on page load by removing it from the function as it will maintain state of the firebase auth is case of page reload.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            window.location = 'thank-you'
            let email = user.email
            console.log(email + " logged in")
        } else {
            window.location = ""
            console.log("not logged in")
        }
    });
```

This listener will automatically detect if a user has logged / signed up into your app using the firebase.auth methods.

Hope this helps.